# My Cargo.toml is displaying some red lines with error couldn't compile serde_derive

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I try to build a project using rust-lang recently (this is my first rust project, and my boss is supporting me to use a new technology in my company). But, I suddenly get some red lines on my Cargo.toml :

```
could not compile `serde_derive`.
error: could not compile `async-trait`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
error: could not compile `rand_chacha`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
error: could not compile `proc-macro-hack`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
error: could not compile `diesel_derives`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I run a command Cargo Run and my project is running well, but these red lines prevent me to tracking an error on my other code in my project (So if there is an error in code, it won't display as there are still exists some errors in another file, it is Cargo.toml)

I am using cargo 1.43.0-nightly (bda50510d 2020-03-02), rustc 1.43.0-nightly (c20d7eecb 2020-03-11), and vs code 1.43 version.

This is my Cargo.toml :

```
[package]
name = "app_base"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["yonathan"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rocket = "0.4.3"
rocket_codegen = "0.4.3"
rocket_contrib = "0.4.3"
rocket_http = "0.4.3"
cookie = "0.11.2"
rocket-json-response = "0.5.10"
diesel = { version = "1.4.3", features = ["postgres"] }
dotenv = "0.15.0"
postgres = { version = "0.17.2", features = ["with-chrono-0_4"] }
serde = { version = "1.0", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0"
json-gettext = "3.1.7"
debug-helper = "0.3.8"
serializers  = "0.2.3"
rocket_cors = { git = "https://github.com/lawliet89/rocket_cors", branch = "master" }
chrono = "0.4"
```

Comment: Does running `cargo build` give any errors?

Comment: The error message says: `To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.` What happened when you did that?

Comment: +1: It is happening for the simple example [here](https://serde.rs/derive.html) too: The `Cargo.toml` file turns **red** with mouse hover hint: could not compile `serde_derive`.  But: cargo run works OK: output: `serialized = {"x":1,"y":2}`

Comment: Since `cargo run` works, I think this is may be `rls` bug.

Comment: when i run the code with --verbose, it displays the same errors(those errors). But if i cargo run or cargo build, everything just running OK, but these red lines prevent me to get another errors from my another code. If it's the rls bug, is there any rls extension for vs code except the official?

Comment: I have try another rls extension and it is working fine, the extension is rust-analyzer. Thanks

Comment: I have exactly the same problem just with `diesel_derives`. Everything is working fine, just the Cargo.toml file is annoyingly red

Answer (score 2):

As this is an RLS (rust language server) bug [which is *closed* apparently, see [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/vscode-rust/issues/749)], a temporary alternative can be using the `rust-analyzer` extension [website [here](https://rust-analyzer.github.io)].

To install the extension, you can launch VSCode, click on the `Extensions` tab on the left and search for `rust-analyzer` in the Marketplace.

> Please note that as mentioned on the website [as of 04/01/2020], this project is still in **ALPHA**, which means it may be prone to breakages.